# Colorbox Close Event not responding on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have color box implementation where on click of a URL(inside the colorbox) should close the colorbox itself. Below is the code:

> **HTML Where on click of a URL opens a ColorBox of Image.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$('.colorbox-link').colorbox({
        transition: "none",
        opacity: 0.4,
        onComplete: function(){
            $.colorbox.resize();
        },
        speed: 300,
        width: 530,
        initialWidth: "530",
        innerWidth: 530,
        maxWidth: 530,
        height:false,
        initialHeight: "400",
        innerHeight: false,
        maxHeight: false,
        preloading:false

    });     
});
</script>

<a id="Preview1" href="openpopup.php" class="colorbox-link">Preview</a>
```

> **POPUP/COLORBOX which opens on click of a Preview URL**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#change').click(function(){

        $('#cboxClose').click();
    });

  });
</script>
<div class="popup-shell">
  <div class="modal-header"> <i id="close-icon" class="icon-close close-trigger"> </i>
    <h2 class="page-title"> Preview Your File </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-body">
    <div class="popup-image-holder"> <a class="demo" href=""> <img src="personal.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <p class="buttons-small"> <a id="accept" href="javascript:;"> accept </a> <a href="javascript:;" id="change"> change </a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in colorbox/popup window, there is a link "change" on click of which color box should close, but it doesn't... It works fine in all other browsers except SAFARI

The [Demo URL](http://ec2-50-19-74-207.compute-1.amazonaws.com/encdec/index.php) where you Can find the application. please see in Safari.

Comment: Your change anchor tag does not have the ID `change`.

Comment: Thanks @kayen but it was just a typo on writing it here.... Problem doesnt solve by correcting it.

Comment: @Amith But That will only refresh the page, that what I dont want to happen

Answer (score 0):

I guess for you there is no need of `<a>` tag because you are using jquery to attach event to it.
try this

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <p class="buttons-small">
       <input type ="button" value ="accept" id="accept" />
       <input type ="button" value ="change" id="change" /> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tag Is not the problem Brother, the problem is close event of colorbox.

Comment: why it is not closing because you are using a href and trying to bind a event to it. Since a href have default click event it wont work. so better try using button

Answer (score 0):

I bet the click event is not really bound to the element. Try using `live` to bind the click event to the element:

```
$('body').live('click', '#change' , function(){
    $('#cboxClose').click();
    //or $.colorbox.close()

});
```